# silverlight Label using PropertyPath

Tags: silverlight-4.0, binding, label, data-annotations

Using silverlight 4, I've set the target of a label to a combobox. The combobox has two bindings set, and its using the wrong one to get the label's contents.

I know I'm supposed to use the Label's **PropertyPath** property to tell it wich binding to use, but I can't find any examples of what to write as the value. My instinct is to use the name of the combo box's property, but that doesn't seem to work.

Removing the second binding will work, but I need both bindings. Can anyone help me with this?

```
[Display(Name = "Manufacturer"))]
public List<dms_Manufacturer> ManufacturerList {get;set;}


<sdk:Label Grid.Row ="4" Grid.Column="0"  
    Target="{Binding ElementName=cmb_Manufacturer}"
    PropertyPath="ItemsSource"  />
<ComboBox Grid.Row ="4" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="cmb_Manufacturer" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ManufacturerList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding dms_Manufacturer, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="cmb_Manufacturer_SelectionChanged"  />
```

Comment: Are you wanting the label text to display "Manufacturer"?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. The label will pick up the text from the data annotation, if it knows wich binding to follow. Currently its using the binding on the SelectedItem property. I can't figure out what the value for property path should be, straight text? a binding to that property? I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<sdk:Label Grid.Row ="4" Grid.Column="0"
       Target="{Binding ElementName=cmb_Manufacturer}" 
       PropertyPath="ManufacturerList"  />
```

Comment: So its the property the other control is being bound to, not the property of the control. Thanks a lot, works just as expected!